# 'this' context different for event handlers in function vs class react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, codesandbox

Why is 'this' (the context) different depending on whether I use a functional or class component in react? I understand how binding works and that my handler will take on the context of the onclick handler (or however it gets used in onclick) but I don't understand why the value is different for these 2 situations. The functional component prints the window object while the class component prints undefined.

How is the synthetic onclick event defined? What is its context? What does it do with its callback?

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = function () {
    console.log(this);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>HandleClick Functional</button>
      <Toggle />
    </div>
  );
}

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>HandleClick Class</button>;
  }
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-context-test-ievog6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Are you sure the functional component prints `window` with that exact code? I'm getting `undefined`. ReactJS doesn't bind it's `onClick` to the element like traditional `onClick` HTML attributes do.

Comment: @NickParsons yup. just added a codesandbox link. i was wondering about traditional onclick methods as well so thanks for that info

Comment: In non-strict mode, `this` in standalone non-arrow functions refers to window. But in strict-mode, `this` in such functions is undefined. Inside ES6 classes, strict mode is always enabled.

Comment: @qrsngky is onClick different in class components vs functional components? I wouldn't think the definition context would matter since it is being passed as a callback to onClick

Comment: If I add `"use strict";` as the first statement inside the function in line 5 (before `console.log(this);`), it logs `undefined`. Even though ESLint says it's unnecessary, the transpilation results show that it does make a difference. Try this: `const handleClick =  function() {"use strict"; console.log(this);};` both buttons will log 'undefined'.

Comment: The function body may look the same, but using a class makes it behaves as if there is an implicit "use strict", and that can make a difference.
Simple examples:
`class A{foo(){console.log(this)}}; test1 = (new A).foo; test1(); //undefined` vs
`function test2(){console.log(this)}; test2(); //Window {...}` (in non-strict mode)  vs
`function test3(){"use strict";console.log(this)}; test3(); //undefined`

Comment: And if you changed line 4 to `const handleClick = () => {` then the `this` refers to the whatever `this` means in `App`. Then the "use strict" makes a difference if it is placed first in App, not the arrow function.

Comment: My apologies, I've reopened the question as the linked question did not apply to react. However, React documentation provides the information that event handlers are not bound to a class automatically, so will not have a defined `this` value by default when used as a handler., [ [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), under "try it on codepen" ]

Comment: Does anyone know where to look for in the source code of React? It should use addEventListener somewhere.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom/src/events/EventListener.js but not sure how they use it to deal with 'onClick' prop

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** - This looks like a bug with CodeSandbox. Your React function component code ends up running in non-strict mode, which causes your `this` value to default to the global object instead of `undefined` as it should be.

---

This behaviour is pretty odd. But like [@qrsngky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4225384/qrsngky) has correctly pointed out in the comments above, the issue is mainly to do with [strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and a result of how CodeSandbox does error handling. Below I've outlined my observations on why your code is behaving as it is.

Functions declared with the `function` keyword have their own value for `this` (their own "this binding"). How that value for [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is set is based on how the function is called. Methods such as [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) are able to set the `this` value for the function they execute.

In strict-mode code, using `fn.apply(undefined)` results in the function `fn` being executed and the `this` value within `fn` being set to `undefined`. However, in non-strict mode code, using `fn.apply(undefined)` results in the `this` value being set to the [*global object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), which in browsers is the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object. So you have different behaviors when a function is called with `undefined` for its `this`-binding, in:

- non-strict mode: `this` = `window` (in browsers)
- strict mode: `this` = `undefined`

When React invokes your `onClick` handler function (`func`), it invokes it by doing `func.apply(context, ...)`, with a `context` set to `undefined` (you can see this via a debugger):

[image]

At this point, you may be thinking that your code doesn't use the `"use strict"` directive anywhere, so it makes sense that when your function is called by React with a `this` of `undefined` it defaults to the global object `window` as you're code isn't running in strict mode. However, it's not as straightforward as that ;). While it may not look like any of your code is running in strict mode, it is actually classified as strict mode code. That's because [JavaScript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (what you've written your react code in), [automatically run in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_modules). Similarly, code within [classes also automatically runs in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_classes). So that begs the question as to why your code is showing `window` then if your code should actually be running in strict mode.

When React code is written it needs to be transpiled into code that the browser can understand and execute. What seems to have occurred is that when your react code was transpiled, CodeSandbox has added a [try-finally wrapper](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/blob/479de7eb3d4477148004e7ab9cd67ffff387a883/packages/app/src/sandbox/eval/transpilers/react-refresh/refresh-transpiler.ts#L189) around your react code (you can see this using a debugger with source-maps disabled):

```js
...
try {
  "use strict";
   ...
   function App() {
     const handleClick = function() {
       console.log(this);
     }
     ...
   }
} finally {
 ...
}
```

We can see that CodeSandbox has attempted to wrap your code within a try-finally block, where it appears as though the `try` block runs in "strict mode" to try and match the same strict mode behavior automatically applied by the JavaScript module your code is originally written in. However, applying `"use strict"` in a block  `{}` that isn't associated with a function has no effect on the code's strictness (see [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) for rules on strict mode). As a result, the try-finally wrapper that CodeSandbox is applying ends up running your code in non-strict/sloppy mode. This causes `this` to be `window` when React calls your onClick handler with `undefined`.

On the other hand, your `class` still works as expected because in the transpiled code it remains as a `class`, so the strict mode behavior around classes remains, and so you see `undefined` as expected.

---

When using React functional components, however, you shouldn't need to refer to `this`, and instead can use hooks such as [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage things like state, or the event object ([`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)) to access the DOM element that was clicked.

Comment: Raised a bug [here](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/6845) about this issue